# What to show border on mouseover event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[data-role=content]").not("#ft").children().live({ 
        mouseover: function () { $(this).css({ border: "1px solid gray" }); }, 
        mouseleave: function () { $(this).css({ border: "0" }); } });
    });
```

This is not working. The border not shown.Can anybody tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Do you tried with `.hover(function(){ // mouse over },function(){ // mouse leave })` function ?

Comment: From the `.live` documentation: *"Chaining methods is not supported. For example, `$("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... );` is not valid and does not work as expected."*. Use `.on` instead.

Comment: but the childrens may add dynamically in future

Comment: @user1400722: So? That does not make a difference, you won't be able to use `.live` like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`.live` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Chaining methods is not supported. For example, `$("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... );` is not valid and does not work as expected.

Therefore `$(...)....children().live()` won't work.

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$("[data-role=content]").not("#ft").on( {
    mouseover: function () { 
        $(this).css({ border: "1px solid gray" }); 
    }, 
    mouseleave: function () { 
        $(this).css({ border: "0" }); 
    }
}, '[data-role=content] > *');
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to just use `> *` as selector for the event delegation. Of course `[data-role=content] > *` only works properly if the  `[data-role=content]` elements are not nested.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZMkA/)